# Spring (boot) URL clashing (due to containment)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and in my controller, I have the below two endpoints:

> @GetMapping("/{id}")
>
> public String foo1(int id) {...}

and

> @GetMapping("/foo/bar")
>
> public String foo2() {...}

**Occasionally**, when I am executing API call to

> .../foo/bar

it is interpolated and actually mapped to **foo1** method (with **id** equals **foo/bar**) and not to **foo2** (as expected).

This is not consistent. it happens from time to time.

What is the best practice here? How can I avoid the clashing?

Is there a way I can get some control over the actual URL-Mapping process spring is performing?
(Let's assume that by now I am already obligated to the foo1 and foo2 mapping and can't change them..)

Comment: Have u tried changing the order of methods ?

Comment: No, because it happens every now and then. There were many times where the mapping was correct and as I expected, so I didn't think it was order-related.
I could try and change the order - but if the process is somehow not deterministic, I might just delay the problem... :(